# How to differ a verb with different meanings using grammar rules

Tags: sentence-meaning

Do you see the difference in the verb meaning between two sentences?

> I miss your excellent cooking!

vs

> I am missing your excellent cooking!

As to me, I suggest the first one is about yearning for it, but the second one - about skipping. Of course, it's only my thought how it's possible sometimes to differ some verbs with different meanings if we don't have additional information about the context. Am I right?

Comment: No, there is no difference in meaning. I disagree with James that "I am missing [something]" is odd - it's just another way of expressing the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second sentence is *marked*.  It is unusual to use present continuous for the verb "to miss" (in this sense).

The usual sentence is "I miss.." This has the common meaning of the words.  If you  say "I'm missing" you have deliberately chosen an odd phrasing.  It's not clear why, or what the intended sense is. Present continuous can indicate "temporary state" so perhaps the speaker is intending to highlight the fact that they expect to enjoy the cooking again in the near future.

It is difficult for learners to use such odd phrasing. If a learner were to use the second sentence, I'd probably just assume it was a mistake, similar to the stereotypical error, "I'm liking [your excellent cooking]"

Comment: James, I have several English books, and there are the verb "miss" isn't among non-continuous verbs there. Are you sure that "miss" is non-continuous verb?

Comment: Pretty sure, but I'll take the DVs if I'm wrong

Comment: Could you say how many of non-continuous verbs there are? I saw about 30, but there wasn't "miss" there.